# OnClick event for on listbox strings

Tags: delphi

I want to convert a string from a ListBox into an event. Like if I have a string which says "Image5", I'd like to get the Image5.Click event in my procedure. Is it possible?

Comment: That line doesn't fill the list box; it reads the currently selected item. Anyhow, it is not clear what you want.

Comment: It sounds like your question is too basic or elementary to be of any use to anyone but you. If you can't call a function and you can't figure out how to call a function, that sounds like you need a tutorial on Delphi, not stack overflow.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well my problem. I want to convert a string (from the ListBox) into an event. Like if I have a string which says "Image5", I'd like to get the Image5.Click; on my procedure.

Comment: @DK64 You can't have an oOnClick for the specific item, but you do know the selected item in the listbox's onclick event. Remember, the OnClick event fires after the selected item has changed.

Comment: `Selected := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];` would be the proper way to do it. (`Strings` is the default property for `TStrings` descendants, so it can be omitted. With a `TStringList` called `SL`, you can access the individual `Strings` by just using `SL[index]` instead of `SL.Strings[index]`. Your question is very unclear, but if your last comment explains it better then you should [edit] your question to ask that instead, and do it by editing instead of putting it in comments where people might not see it.

Comment: @Warren P It sounds like your comment is too elementary and you need to read better and well understand questions because some nice people understood my problem and they helped me. Regards.

Comment: The downvotes are not because we don't like you, it's because the question is not following the rules in the FAQ. Please read them and it will help you out, plus everyone else who comes later and reads your questions and the answers people left for that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this should work (it's a double-click handler for the `ListBox`) if all the components in the list box are the same type (for instance, `TImage`):

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Image: TImage;
  Selected: string;
begin
  if ListBox1.ItemIndex = -1 then
    Exit;
  Selected := ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex];
  Image := FindComponent(Selected) as TImage;
  if Assigned(Image) then
    if Assigned(Image.OnClick) then
      // You can access Image.OnClick here. In this case, I'll
      // just call it directly with a nil Sender parameter.
      Image.OnClick(nil);
end;
```

If all you want to do is call the `Image.OnClick`, though, you can do it more directly (as David mentioned in his comment to my answer):

```
if Assigned(Image) then
  Image.Click;    // Automatically calls OnClick if assigned
```

Comment: `if Assigned(Image.OnClick) then` is not needed since the `Click` method will also do that.

Comment: @David: I caught that, but then thought perhaps calling `OnClick` directly might be a better idea, so I changed the example. Thanks for the catch, though. Fixed to include both, as it's not clear what the poster is asking.

Comment: I would always prefer using the `Click` method of a control. It will pass an appropriate `Sender` for a start. It just feels much cleaner to me.

Comment: Unless you want to send a different `Sender`. :-) But you're right; for most cases, it's much cleaner.